# Searching for maven artifacts directly form Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, maven-3

I would like to know if it is somehow possible to search for maven artifacts directly from m2eclipse plugin. Normaly i just use google and paste artifact  from browser into pom.xml.

Is there any better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addendum to the other answers: Activate Maven indexes by checking `Window > Preferences > Maven > Download repository index updates on startup`. That way you will always find the latest versions of all the libraries in your configured repositories.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Right-click the pom.xml, select `Maven > Add dependency`

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Eclipse POM editor, you will have a tab labelled "Dependencies" -- click on "Add" in there and you will be able to search for artifacts -- you will get a list of results and then select them to add as dependencies.

Comment: BTW if Eclipse doesn't open by default the POM Editor, right-click on the pom.xml and select Open with -> Maven POM Editor.